# Using range in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a query using the RANGE in elastic search, but when I run the query it returns results that are of the defined range.

```
POST crawler9/crawler-vehicles9/_search
{
    "_source" : ["price", "version"],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{ 
                "range": { 
                    "price": {
                        "gte": 40000,
                        "lte": 50000
                    } 
                }    
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the results are correct but some are priced at 405990 and 444673. The range ranges from 40000 to 50000.

Comment: That's because your price field has a string type in the mapping and for strings "405990" and "444673" are < than "50000". You need to fix the type to use a numeric type and then it will work as you expect.